# Spring Boot OAuth2 Could not obtain access token

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I'm tring SSO Login with Spring Boot and OAuth2.

I have an oauth2 client running on http://localhost:8001/demo and an oauth2 authorization server running on http://localhost:9001/uaa

In result, after approval page it direct to the approval page again and again.I'm getting back "**org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Could not obtain access token**" from the client.

I have no idea what's going on. I did this with Spring Boot1.5 everything seems to be find

[Code](https://github.com/sebarswee/spring-oauth2-demo)

Comment: Why did you enabled authentication for "/oauth/**" ?? .antMatchers("/oauth/**").authenticated() ??

Comment: if i don't i got error when direct to /oauth/authorize, and i tried todisable authentication for "/oauth/token", i got something like "Access is denied (user is anonymous)"